# I am trying to set up a simple http server in port 8000 and connect remotely. UFW is open at 8000, but the connection is refused

Tags: networking, firewall, ip, port, ufw

I am new to networking and servers and I am trying to get started by setting up a simple server in port 8000 in a remote host with python -m http.server 8000 and telnet from my local computer

I've opened port 8000 for tcp traffic and im getting the following outputs for ufw status and  netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
8000                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8000/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
1000/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8000 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
8000/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
1000/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:38463         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1233793/node        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33899         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1233876/node        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::9445                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::9101                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::9103                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

But still, I am not being able to telnet the IP from my local computer. The connection timeouts   Any clue what's going on? I am not using google cloud or aws

Comment: You have a firewall somewhere in the path that blocks the connection.

Comment: Any clues where?

Comment: Run traceroute; any reported host in between could block the connection.